# Is the empty family of sets pairwise disjoint?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

„A family of sets is pairwise disjoint or mutually disjoint if every two different sets in the family are disjoint.“ – from [Wikipedia article "Disjoint sets"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_sets)

What about the empty family of sets? Is it also pairwise disjoint?

I think, that the empty family of sets is pairwise disjoint, because statements of the form $\forall x \in \emptyset:\ldots$ are always true. Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are right.  It is vacuously true.  Here's a more detailed explanation of why:

In math, either a statement is true, or its negation is true (but not both).  That means, for example, either the statement (a) $\forall x \in \emptyset$, $x^{2} = 1$ or its negation, (b) $\exists x \in \emptyset$ such that $x^{2} \neq 1$, is true, and the other is false.

It's clear that statement (b) is false since $\exists x \in \emptyset$ is a false statement.  So, since statement (b) is false, its negation, statement (a), must be true (it's called vacuously true).

Comment: "In math, either a statement is true, or its negation is true (but not both)"
actually, this is only valid in classical logic, but it really doesn't matter for this question

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is *not* a family of sets which are pairwise disjoint, then there *exists* $A_1,A_2\in A$ such that $A_1\neq A_2$ and $A_1\cap A_2\neq\varnothing$.

So... yes.